# Bizarre Python/Selenium looping behavior

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a program that saves the urls I visit to a file, then highlights them in the browser so I don't waste time visiting them again while searching through Google. The relevant part of my code follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

urllist = []
with open('urls.txt') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        #[:-1] gets rid of newline "\n" at end of string
        urllist.append(line[:-1])

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com/search?q=wikipedia")


for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
    try:
        if "google.com" not in a.get_attribute('href') and "googleusercontent.com" not in a.get_attribute('href'):
            if a.get_attribute('href') in urllist:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'", a)
    except:
        pass
```

And it works beautifully.

But that only highlights one page of results. I want to highlight every page during my browsing session. So I add a loop to check a few times every second whether I have manually navigated to a new page, and if it detects a new urls, highlight the page (a bit clunky – but humor me).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

urllist = []
with open('urls.txt') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        #[:-1] gets rid of newline "\n" at end of string
        urllist.append(line[:-1])

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com/search?q=wikipedia")

while True:
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(0.2)
    if url != driver.current_url:
        for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
            try:
                if "google.com" not in a.get_attribute('href') and "googleusercontent.com" not in a.get_attribute('href'):
                    if a.get_attribute('href') in urllist:
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'", a)
            except:
                pass
```

Except that now, it no longer works as I navigate. A little testing shows that the find_elements_by_xpath method is now returning an empty list. And have no idea why – a working piece of code should still work when I put it in a loop, shouldn't it? The hero who can figure this out will be my champion.

Comment: I am a bit confuse you have assigned `url = driver.current_url` and after provide some sleep you are verifying  `if url != driver.current_url:` how this going to work??

Comment: Think of it like this:


url = driver.current_url sets url variable equal to present url. 


time.sleep(0.2) sleeps for a moment to slow loop down.

if url != driver.current_url: checks url variable from a moment ago agains current url. If they no longer match, then the program knows that you have manually navigated the browser to a new url, and enters a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert but looking at this code few things can happen -

1) in your for loop you get the link references - for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')

2) Now while loop is being executed the code is reading element href property - a.get_attribute('href')

3) Considering that if you navigate while loop is being executed, selenium will throw StaleElementReferenceException

4) you can probably try catching this specific exception and reinitialize your loop variable reference.

here is the java code which works perfectly fine -

```
    public void testThis() throws InterruptedException {
    DriverFactory df = new DriverFactory(); // internal implementation to get driver
    WebDriver driver = df.getDriver();
    List<String> visitedLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    visitedLinks.add("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    visitedLinks.add("https://www.wikipedia.org/");

    driver.get("https://google.com/search?q=wikipedia");
    List<WebElement> allLinksInPage = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            if (!currentUrl.equals(driver.getCurrentUrl())) {
                allLinksInPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a"));

                for (WebElement we : allLinksInPage) {
                    if (visitedLinks.contains(we.getAttribute("href"))) {
                        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'",
                                we);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            allLinksInPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a"));
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps.